# How to fix my code-- KeyError but my code was working before?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

nothing in the data has changed, and all of a sudden my code has stopped working, even when reverting to previous versions. I'm not sure why, and I can't figure it out. I've compared previous version and am hoping you can find something I'm missing, or recommend a fix to this new KeyError.

Like I stated, I've looked through the data and nothing has changed in that, so I'm guessing the issue lies within my code, but even reverting to an earlier version (which previously worked) isn't working.

Before this, I have two dictionaries, state_code (maps each state to a region code) and states (maps each state to its respective abbreviation)

```
excel_file = r'/Users/amandawhiting/Desktop/PA_spending_excel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
df = df.rename(columns={'DAMAGE_CATEGORY_CODE': 'damageCode', 
                     'FEDERAL_SHARE_OBLIGATED':'FedShareObligated', 'PROJECT_AMOUNT': 'ProjectAmount'})  
df = df[df['FedShareObligated']>= 0] 
df = df[df['ProjectAmount'] >= 0] # Removes missing/null projects
df = df[df['damageCode'] != 'A - Debris Removal']
df = df[df['damageCode'] != 'B - Protective Measures']
df = df[df['damageCode'] != 'Z - State Management']
df = df[df['damageCode'] != 'H - Fire Management']
df = df.drop_duplicates() 
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 

df2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/amandawhiting/Desktop/DisasterDeclarationsSummaries.csv", usecols = ['disasterNumber', 'fyDeclared', 'state'])
df2 = df2[df2['fyDeclared'] > 1991]
df2 = df2[df2['fyDeclared'] < 2017]
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)  # Resets index
df2['disasterNumber'] = df2['disasterNumber'].astype(int) 

fulldf = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on = 'disasterNumber', right_on = 'disasterNumber', how = 'inner',) 
fulldf = fulldf.drop_duplicates() 
fulldf = fulldf.reset_index(drop=True)

fulldf["Region"] = fulldf['state'].map(state_code)

df_state = fulldf.copy()
df_fyr = fulldf.copy()
df_region = fulldf.copy()
df_damageCat = fulldf.copy()

fulldf["TotalProjectCost, 1.3%"] = round(fulldf["ProjectAmount"] * .013)                                                                                                                   
fulldf["TotalProjectCost, 1.6%"] = round(fulldf["ProjectAmount"] * .016)                                                                      
fulldf["TotalProjectCost, 15%"] = round(fulldf["ProjectAmount"] * .15) 
fulldf["TotalProjectCost, 46%"] = round(fulldf["ProjectAmount"] * .46)
```

The following lines are what specifically are not producing the previous successful result:

```
df_state=df_state[["ProjectAmount"]].groupby('state').sum()

df_state['TotalProjectCost'] = ['${:,.2f}MM'.format(x) for x in     df_state['ProjectAmount'] * (.15) / 1000000]


display(df_state)
```

Expected results:
Table with each state mapped to value of Project Amount and also mapped to project amount formatted in millions.

Actual results: Key Error

```
   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-31-6b223454133a> in <module>
   ----> 1 df_state=df_state[["ProjectAmount"]].groupby('state').sum()
      2 
      3 df_state['TotalProjectCost'] = ['${:,.2f}MM'.format(x) for x in    df_state['ProjectAmount'] * (.15) / 1000000]
      4 
      5 

   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, **kwargs)
   7630         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
   7631                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze,
   -> 7632                        observed=observed, **kwargs)
   7633 
   7634     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, normalize=False,

   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
   2108         raise TypeError('invalid type: {}'.format(obj))
   2109 
   -> 2110     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)

   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, **kwargs)
    358                                                     sort=sort,
    359                                                        observed=observed,
   --> 360                                                        mutated=self.mutated)
    361 
    362         self.obj = obj

   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
    576                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr,    None
    577             else:
   --> 578                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    579         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    580             # Add key to exclusions

   KeyError: 'state'
```

Comment: The correct syntax is: `df_state.groupby('state')[["ProjectAmount"]].sum()`. The column to be aggregated must come after the groupby call. Otherwise you subset and then group, and "state" is no longer present. Hence the error. I find it hard to believe this line of code was ever working for you.

Comment: If `df_state.groupby('state')[["ProjectAmount"]].sum()` is not working I can only imagine you're suffering from whitespace issues. . . something like `df_state.groupby(df.state.str.strip())[["ProjectAmount"]].sum()`  will work but you should look into fixing the code that creates the state column, or preprocess it beforehand.

Comment: @cs95 previous one worked, and gave me the same result I was seeing before it broke. I'm really not sure how it was working (I'm sure you're 100% correct) but it was!

Comment: @cs95 Thanks yet again. I am eternally grateful to the stack overflow overlords.

Comment: @cs95 if you feel so inclined.. follow up question: if I wanted to sort by a column `TotalProjectCost, 15%` rather than `ProjectAmount` why does this break the code? Especially if I move `fulldf["TotalProjectCost, 15%"] = round(fulldf["ProjectAmount"] * .15)` before I make the copy of the df?